# exp(x)=e^x proof

Tags: taylor-expansion, exponential-function

I have got Taylor series for function exp(x) for which
$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}^k \mathrm{exp}(x)}{\mathrm{d}x^k}=\mathrm{exp}(x) \ \ \ \forall k \in \mathbb{N}.$$

Now I want to show, that this is an exponential function:
$$ \mathrm{exp}(x)=(\mathrm{exp}(1))^x$$

Can someone present the proof how to show this? I have already proven (with Euler's formula)  that $$ \mathrm{exp}(x+y)=\mathrm{exp}(x)\times\mathrm{exp}(y) \ \mathrm{and} \ \mathrm{exp}(-x)=\frac{1}{\mathrm{exp}(x)}.$$

Comment: How have you defined the exponential functions $a^x$?

Comment: Note that by the last two properties, it suffices to show that for $x \in [0, 1]$, $\exp(x) = (\exp(1))^x$.

Comment: What is your definition of $(\exp(1))^x$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the title of this post, I'll assume you're looking for a proof of $\exp(x)=e^x$

The proof of this equivalence will ultimately depend on how you have defined the exponential functions $a^x$. One approach you could take, and arguably the most reasonable one, is to define $a^{(\cdot)}$ as follows:

> Given some real number $a>0$, the exponential function $a^{(\cdot)}$ is the unique anywhere-continuous function (this means that there exists a point in $\mathbb{R}$ where $a^x$ is continuous) that satisfies $a^1=a$ and $a^{x+y}=a^x a^y$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$

The requirement that $a^x$ be continuous at a point cannot be omitted unless it is substituted for some other "satisfactory" requirement (e.g. $a^x$ is differentiable at $0$). Without it, one can can construct highly pathological functions that satisfy $a^1=a$ and $a^{x+y}=a^x a^y$, but are discontinuous.

Once you have defined $a^x$ this way, all you need to do is verify that $\exp(x)$ satisfies these three conditions. You've shown that $\exp(x)$ is differentiable, so it is clearly continuous. You've also shown that $\exp(x+y)=\exp(x)\exp(y)$, so you only need to verify that $\exp(1)=e$. This will depend on how $e$ is defined. If you define $e$ to be the sum of the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}$, then $\exp(1)=e$ immediately follows from the Maclaurin series of $\exp(x)$. If you define $e$ otherwise, then proving the equivalence will require some work.